# What's the best idiom for creating an EmberJS view that can show all its child-views, or just one?

Tags: ember.js

Say I have a model App.Page, an ArrayController of App.Page, and an App.PageView to render each App.Page.

I'm trying to figure out how to best implement *App.MyPagesView* so it works like so:

- **if *App.showAllPages* is true**: I want MyPagesView to contain an App.PageView(s) for displaying each of the App.Page in App.pages
- **Else**: I want MyPagesView only show one App.PageView, bound to App.pages.currentPage.

The most straightforward implementation that occurs to me is using a template like so:

```
// MyPagesViewApproach1
{{#unless App.showAllPages}}
    {{view App.PageView pageBinding="pages.currentPage"}}
{{else}}
    {{#each pages}}
        {{view App.PageView pageBinding="this"}}
    {{/each}}
{{/unless}}
```

**But won't this create new views for the existing models every time the user toggles *showAllPages* on and off?** Also, I get emberJS warnings about performance issues when I try to use this template.

The PageView(s) could be quite complex and expensive to render. I'd really like to create a PageView once for each Page, and just remove/hide the irrelevant PageViews from the DOM when they're not in use.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    showAllPages: false,
    pages: Ember.ArrayController.create({
        content: []
        currentPage: null
    }),
    ready: function () {
        this.pages.pushObject(App.Page.create({title: 'Page One'});
        this.pages.pushObject(App.Page.create({title: 'Some Other Page'});
        this.pages.pushObject(App.Page.create({title: 'Grrreatest Page Evar'});
        this.pagesController.set('currentPage',
            this.pagesController.get('firstObject'));
    }
});
App.Page = Ember.Object.extend({
    title: null
    // etc, etc...
});
App.PageView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'page',
    page: null    // should be bound to an App.Page
});

App.MyPagesView_Approach1 = Ember.View.extend({
    pagesBinding: 'Elicitation.pages'
    // ???
});
App.MyPagesView_Approach2 = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    // ???
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="page">
    The title of this page is {{ page.title }}
</script>

{{view App.MyPagesView }}
```

**To recap, what's the proper EmberJS-y way to implement MyPagesView so it responds to *App.showAllPages* without re-creating all the views each time its toggled?**

Should it be some sort of ContainerView? Or should I use the unless/else template shown at the top of the question? Or something entirely different? I feel like a really simple solution exists in EmberJS, but its elluding me.

Comment: I'm starting to think Ember.CollectionView might be the best starting point, combined with an observer that watches App.pages.content and sets isVisible=false on !currentPage if inAllPagesMode. A little convoluted, but could this be a good direction to head?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the best I've come up with, encapsulated as a re-usable View class called "CurrentCollectionView". I'm using CollectionView, and using view.set('isVisible') to hide/show appropriate child views. Basically use it like a CollectionView, but you can set currentContent to hide all but one element of content, or use showAllContent to override currentContent.

```
App.CurrentCollectionView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    showAllContent: false,
    currentContent: null,

    currentContentChanged: function () {
        console.log("Elicitation.PagesView.currentContentChanged()");
        var showAllContent = this.get('showAllContent');

        if (Ember.none(showAllContent) || !showAllContent) {
            var contents = this.get('content');
            var currentContent = this.get('currentContent');
            this.get('childViews').forEach(function (view, i) {
                var isVisible = contents.objectAt(i) == currentContent;
                view.set('isVisible', isVisible);
            });
        } else {
            this.get('childViews').forEach(function (view) {
                view.set('isVisible', true);
            });
        }
    }.observes('currentContent', 'showAllContent', 'childViews')
});
```

An example of using CurrentCollectionView to implement MyPagesView:

```
App.MyPagesView = App.CurrentCollectionView.extend({
    itemViewClass: App.PageView,
    contentBinding: 'App.pages',
    currentContentBinding: 'App.pages.currentPage',
    showAllContentBinding: 'App.showAllPages',
});
```

or as using it inline as a template:

```
{{view App.CurrentCollectionView itemViewClass="App.PageView" contentBinding="App.pages" currentContentBinding="App.pages.currentPage" showAllContentBinding="App.showAllPages"}}
```

Hope somebody else finds this useful and/or can improve on it (please!)